# Maven Configuration for Converting a WSDL 1.1 to WSDL 2.0 Using woden-converter-maven-plugin

Tags: java, web-services, maven, wsdl

I'm looking to convert a WSDL version 1.1 into a WSDL 2.0 format as part of our maven build process.

I've [come across](http://ssagara.blogspot.ie/2009/01/converting-wsdl11-to-wsdl20-using-woden.html) the Woden Converter utility which uses XSL to do this conversion, and would like to use it. However, there seems to be no documentation or examples (that I can find) on how to configure or use the related maven plugin: woden-converter-maven-plugin

Does anyone have experience with this, and could they please share the maven plugin config details?

Justification (for those that require it):
We have a contract-first Web Service and have a recent requirement to expose our WSDL in 2.0 format to one particular client. To save on maintaining two identical WSDLs, we'd like to maintain the 1.1 wsdl and have the build process auto-generate the 2.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here are the sources for the plugin](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/webservices/woden/trunk/java/woden-converter-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/woden/converter/maven2/ConverterMojo.java). There's not much you can set. Check the fields. You can set those up in the `<configuration/>` section of your plugin.

Consider this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.woden</groupId>
        <artifactId>woden-converter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0M9</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>convert</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>convert</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdl><!-- File or URL of wsdl1.1 document.Also multiple
                         WSDL files can be specified as a comma separated
                         list. -->
                    </wsdl>
                    <targetNS>
                         <!-- New target namespace for WSDL2.0 document. -->
                    </targetNS>
                    <targetDir>
                         <!-- Target directory for output, default 
                              location is project build directory. -->
                    </targetDir>
                    <sourceDir><!-- Source directory for output. --></sourceDir>
                    <verbose><!-- Verbose mode --></verbose>
                    <overwrite><!-- Overwrite existing files. --></overwrite>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: That's great thanks. I didn't realize you could just deduce configuration setup from the source.

Comment: It's actually, pretty much as simple. Just look for the javadoc annotations and you'll spot the fields that are part of the plugin's `<configuration/>`.